# How Can I Change The Content Of HTML Element Using PHP Include

Tags: php, html

I basically have a php header like this

```
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
</body>
```

That is contained in a header.php file, but when I'm on another page for example

```
<?php include(header.php) ?>
```

How would I make it so that you could change the h1 Title in the header.php on the destination webpage.  I have tried putting  in the h1 in the header, and then putting  on the destination page, but this hasn't worked for me.  Is there any way to simplify do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking:

header.php:

```
<body>
<h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>
</body>
```

other page

```
<?php 
$title ='fish';
include('header.php');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, It is kind of silly that it was something as simple as statement order.